# jqGrid - disable user column resizing

Tags: jqgrid

How can you prevent users from manually resizing jqGrid columns?

Can you return `false` from the `resizeStop` [event handler](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Look at the documentation for the columns](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options)

There is "resizable" property on the column that you could set to false to prevent your columns from being resized.